# I am getting an ```AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cityArray'```

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, attributeerror

This is a part of my code I printed some values instead of returning them just for checking purposes regardless I am getting an Attribute error while running this code. I did define the cityArray but it still throws an error.

This basically stores a CSV file and runs a linear search.

````
class City:#City classs
    def __init__(self,cid,cname,cstate,pop,cities):         #initilize the variables 

        self.cid= cid
        self.cname= cname                                  ##sets them all as empty lists
        self.cstate=cstate 
        self.pop= pop        
        self.cities= cities
        def __str__(self):                                  #return fuction to put out the final value
            print("cid: %s; cname: %s;cstate: %s; cases:%s"%(cid,cname,cstate,cities))

class COV19Library:#library classs

    def __init__(self):
        self.issorted=False 
        self.cityArray=[]
        self.size=0

    def LoadData(self, filename: str):           #loads the data feom excel sheet into those empty lists
        file = csv.DictReader(open(filename))    #as it is in a directory everything is linked
        for temp in file:

            cid = temp["City_ID"]      #all the city ID
            pop = temp['POP10']        #the population
            cities = temp['6/30/20']   #the latest number of case

            t = temp['City State'].split()    #splits city and state

            cstate = [word for word in t if word.isupper()]    #A comprehension and a Bool to identify states
            cname = [x for x in t if x not in cstate]          #remove the states from the initial list and we get cities 
            #print(cname)           #test
        for r in range(len(cid)):
            self.cityArray.append(City(cid,cname,cstate,pop,cities))

    def linearSearch(self, city, attribute):                    #linear search algorythum
        #print(cid)

        if attribute == "name":
            for r in cname:
                if r == city:
                    print(r)
                else:
                    print("City not found")
        elif attribute=="id":
            for z in self.cid:
                if z == city:
                    print(z)
                else:
                    print("City not found")```


ERROR: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Proj.py", line 142, in <module>
    COV19Library.LoadData(0,'cov19_city.csv') 
  File "Proj.py", line 36, in LoadData
    self.cityArray.append(City(cid,cname,cstate,pop,cities))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cityArray'
````

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2):

The bug:

`COV19Library.LoadData(0,'cov19_city.csv')`

The call is passing 0 as the first argument. This number is assigned to `self` which leads to the error.

Create an instance of the class and use it:

```
covid = COV19Library()
covid.LoadData('a_file_name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From your error traceback, the line that seems to be at fault is:

```
COV19Library.LoadData(0,'cov19_city.csv')
```

From your class, we can see that LoadData takes an instance of itself, and the filename of the csv file. You're passing in 0 as the first argument, which causes LoadData to load the instance 0, which is creating that int error.

To fix this, you need to create an instance of your class like:

```
library = COV19Library()
library.LoadData('cov19_city.csv')
```

May I also ask, why are you looping twice in the same function? Would it not be easier if you put

```
self.cityArray.append(City(cid,cname,cstate,pop,cities))
```

right after

```
cname = [x for x in t if x not in cstate]
```

EDIT:

```
class City:  # City classs
    def __init__(self, cid, cname, cstate, pop, cities):  # initilize the variables

        self.cid = cid
        self.cname = cname  # sets them all as empty lists
        self.cstate = cstate
        self.pop = pop
        self.cities = cities

        def __str__(self):  # return fuction to put out the final value
            print("cid: %s; cname: %s;cstate: %s; cases:%s" %
                (cid, cname, cstate, cities))


class COV19Library:  # library classs

    def __init__(self):
        self.issorted = False
        self.cityArray = []
        self.size = 0

    def LoadData(self, filename: str):  # loads the data feom excel sheet into those empty lists
        # as it is in a directory everything is linked
        file = csv.DictReader(open(filename))
        for temp in file:

            cid = temp["City_ID"]  # all the city ID
            pop = temp['POP10']  # the population
            cities = temp['6/30/20']  # the latest number of case

            t = temp['City State'].split()  # splits city and state

            # A comprehension and a Bool to identify states
            cstate = [word for word in t if word.isupper()]
            # remove the states from the initial list and we get cities
            cname = [x for x in t if x not in cstate]
            # print(cname)           #test
            self.cityArray.append(City(cid, cname, cstate, pop, cities))

    def linearSearch(self, city, attribute):  # linear search algorythum
        # print(cid)

        for r in self.cityArray:
            if r.attribute == city:
                print(r)
            else:
                print("City not found")
```

To answer your comment, you keep getting AttributeError: 'COV19Library' object has no attribute 'cname'

If you look at the constructor of your COV19Library class:

```
class COV19Library:  # library classs

    def __init__(self):
        self.issorted = False
        self.cityArray = []
        self.size = 0
```

cname isn't one of the variables in this method, therefore it doesn't exist in the library. Cname can be accessed if you call instances of the City class though, which is what your cityArray is storing.

Knowing this, you can loop through the city array:

```
    def linearSearch(self, city, attribute):  # linear search algorythum
        # print(cid)

        for r in self.cityArray:
            if r.attribute == city:
                print(r)
            else:
                print("City not found")
```

To call this method you do something like:

```
library.linearSearch('TX',cstate)
```

Let's go through each of the steps:

1. When the function is called, it takes in the current instance of COV19Library, the value you're trying to find (String or int), and which attribute you want to pass in. (Variable Name)
2. The program loops through the city array that you've already made in LoadData() and each loop variable is called r
3. It compares the attribute of r, and sees if the value you passed in is the same as the value of r's attribute
4. This loops until it is found, or if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I have a problem in that line too. Basically, I wanna store everything in that "cityArray" and call that later for my linear search, but I think I am using it in the wrong way. I am using a for loop for so that it stores everything from that list. Regardless I think I got it wrong. Any tips ?

Comment: Your linear search should iterate through self.cityArray instead of self.cid or cname because you're trying to find a specific city in the city array. I'd be able to give more detail on how to help if you tell me what kind of variable you're passing into the city parameter in your linear search!

Comment: So the linear search takes the name city which can either be a name as a str or int as a city id, its defined by the attribute beside it. hence the "if statement". I tried using self.cname but it gives me an error: AttributeError: 'COV19Library' object has no attribute 'cname'. I get that but I don't know how to call that particular list of elements.  and sorry for the messy code been trying different things to make it work.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to help you with this new problem.